# What conferences & events should we have a presence at?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I don't know if many of you know, but Robert recently posted a blog about [how we can promote our site.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) In it he offers to match our dedication to helping the site grow, with resources to do just that.

So, in your opinion, what do you think are the key places that we need to be to really help this site take off?

<sub>*(And because I like formatting so much, going to borrow from [webapps.](http://webapps.stackexchange.com))</sub>

For each answer, please identify the following:

> **Name**
>
> **Dates**
>
> **Location**
>
> **Brief Summary**
>
> **Ways we can be involved** (if you have ideas such as:  be a sponsor, have a booth, etc)

Answer (score 6):

**Name: Game Developers Conference**

**Dates: March - TBD**

**Location: San Francisco, CA**

**Brief Summary:**

> ...is the largest annual gathering of professional video game developers, focusing on learning, inspiration, and networking. The event comprises an expo, networking events, awards shows such as the Independent Games Festival and the Game Developers Choice Awards, and a variety of tutorials, lectures, and roundtables by industry professionals on game-related topics...

**Ways we can be involved:** Either a booth, or a sponsored party.  Similar to what IGDA does at GDC.  Maybe joint IGDA/GameDev sessions etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Local IGDA Chapter Meetings**

There are a [lot of chapters](http://www.igda.org/chapters) and each have their own schedule of events.

One thing we could do is hand out business cards or fliers.  Maybe set talk to the local leaders and set up part of a meeting to give a brief presentation of what it's about and examples of good questions/answers.  It's smaller in scope and much more hands on with local people who are generally in the industry.

Comment: the GGDA has an expo called SIEGE every year in october. www.siegecon.net